# Error occurs while calling HttpPut and HttpDelete in C# WebAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have a WebAPI 2 controller. Very easy, very simple:

```
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    // GET api/values
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }

    // GET api/values/5
    public string Get(int id)
    {
        return "value";
    }

    // POST api/values
    public void Post([FromBody]string value)
    {
    }

    // PUT api/values/5
    public void Put(int id, string value)
    {
    }

    // DELETE api/values/5
    public void Delete(int id)
    {
    }
}
```

Get and Post methods work well. But Delete and Put do not work. And this error occurs:

> HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
>   The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

*All methods work well in IIS Express. But not in IIS Local
Any idea why is that happening?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

From where you are sending request to this methods? From AJAX request? GET (with id) PUT and DELETE have same route URL. You have to specify the verb if you are calling via AJAX. Otherwise application gets confused between GET, PUT and DELETE.

Comment: My client is calling my APIs from his Android app. He specified the verb. Also I checked it from Postman. Same result.

Comment: I have tried your exact code from Postman and it is working. Did you try the put parameters as query string, like this: http://localhost:62454/api/values/5?value=str

Comment: this is exactly what I am doing:
http://localhost/pinstogram/api/Values/5 in PUT method

Comment: I think there must be something wrong in my config files. Because I tried in a new WebAPI application and it worked. But I cannot find the mistake.

Comment: Did you check your WebApiConfig.cs for routing mapping? Did you check your web.config whether all verbs are allowed in the "handlers" section?

Comment: I'm not sure about theme. I have to match them by a reference. I'm not sure that I know every things about configs